# How many partitions does pyspark create while reading a csv of a relatively small size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I start a pyspark session in shell by running
`pyspark --master yarn --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 4G`

The cluster starts successfully.

I have a csv with 100000 rows and whose size is 175.46 MBs on disk.

I try to read it and check the number of partitions. The behaviour is very erratic here. It sometimes is 16 partitions and sometimes it is lesser than that. I can try to read the same csv again and again and the number of partitions decreases progressively. The number of partitions reduces erratically but, necessarily reduces. It never increases from what the previous number of partitions was. Attaching the screenshot for one such instance as well

[image]

As you can see, I am reading the exact same CSV and the number of partitions is reducing erratically. Can you please help me understand what is happening here? How is spark deciding the number of partitions and why the element of seeming randomness to it?